# Match strings against a pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework

How should I compare multiple strings against the pattern?

Values:

```
var items = new List<string> {"item1", "item2", "item123", "new_item123"};
```

Pattern:

```
"%item1%" - I receive this option with an external system
```

Expected result: "item1", "item123", "new_item123"

We using entity framework to search data in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you probably could use a regular expression:

```
var pattern = new Regex("/item1/");
var items = new List<string> {"item1", "item2"};

var matches = items.Where(pattern.IsMatch);
```

why not just have:

```
var items = new List<string> {"item1", "item2"};
var matches = items.Where(item => item.Contains("item1"));
```

Comment: the first part of the code won't compile (regex is not declared)

Comment: @nvoigt, I rushed a little bit, please see the changes in question

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it with a `RegEx` you can use this:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^item1$");
var result = items.Where(x => r.IsMatch(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
string ptrn = "item1";
foreach(string s in items) {
   if(s.IndexOf(ptrn) > -1) Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: I don't think he really searches for percentage signs.

Comment: A string of "tem" would match, while "item11" would not with your code. He is looking for things that have "item1" in them.